# How to override specific routes in spring cloud gateway in properties based configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have 2 profiles test and myteam and therefore 2 configuration files application-test.yml and application-myteam.yml

application-test.yml contains routes from all applications(based upon master branch host)
eg:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: app1
          uri: https://app1.company.com
          predicates:
            - Path = /api/msp/app1/someOperation/{id}
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=2
```

and several other routes for other apps.

What I want to achieve is override only subset of routes and keep other routes the same (preferably without copying everything from test) in to myteam. In the above example I want to only override route with id app1 while keeping every other route the same as in test on myteam profile.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this in application.properties:

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://service1:8081

If it doesn't work you can define a variable "rewrite.backend.uri" in the application.yml, like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: rewrite
        uri: ${rewrite.backend.uri:http://service1:8081}
```

then you can override it in application.properties.

Comment: Requires proper formatting